# How is a Lie algebra called whose derived series vanishes after infinitely many steps?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra and let
$$
  \mathfrak{g}^{(0)}
  \supseteq
  \mathfrak{g}^{(1)}
  \supseteq
  \mathfrak{g}^{(2)}
  \supseteq
  \mathfrak{g}^{(3)} 
  \supseteq
  \dotsb
$$
be the derived series of $\mathfrak{g}$, given by $\mathfrak{g}^{(0)} := \mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{g}^{(i+1)} = [\mathfrak{g}^{(i)}, \mathfrak{g}^{(i)}]$ for every $i \geq 0$.

> **Question.**
> Does the property $\bigcap_{i \geq 0} \mathfrak{g}^{(i)} = 0$ have a name?

If $\mathfrak{g}$ is finite-dimensional, then this property means precisely that $\mathfrak{g}$ is solvable. But for infinite-dimensional Lie algebras this is in general not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called "residually solvable" (or "residually soluble" in British English).

This is part of a general terminology. Let P be a property of algebras that is stable under finite direct products and under taking subalgebras. An algebra $A$ is said to be residually P if for any pair  $(x,y)$ of distinct elements in $A$ there is a quotient $p:A\to B$ such that $p(x)\neq p(y)$ and such that $B$ has Property P. This is the same as asking that the intersection of (2-sided) ideals $I$ such that $A/I$ has Property P, is trivial.

For instance, if $(\mathfrak{g}^i)_{i\ge 1}$ is the lower central series, $\bigcap_i\mathfrak{g}^i=\{0\}$ means that $\mathfrak{g}$ is residually nilpotent.

Examples of residually solvable Lie algebras are free Lie algebras (they're even residually nilpotent). In particular, the property "residually solvable", unlike solvable, does not pass to quotients.